# No suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "const char *" exists

Tags: c++, casting

I am trying to delete a `.txt` file but the filename is stored in a variable of type `std::string`. The thing is, the program does not know the name of the file beforehand so I can't just use `remove("filename.txt");`

```
string fileName2 = "loInt" + fileNumber + ".txt";
```

Basically what I want to do is:

```
remove(fileName2);
```

However, it tells me that I cannot use this because it gives the me error:

> No suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "const char *" exists.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
remove(fileName2.c_str());
```

will do the trick.

The `c_str()` member function of a `std::string` gives you the `const char *` C-style version of the string that you can use.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change it to:

```
remove(fileName2.c_str());
```

`c_str()` will return the string as a type `const char *`.

Answer (score 1):

When you need to convert `std::string` to `const char*` you can use the `c_str()` method.

```
std::string s = "filename";
remove(s.c_str());
```